# An alternative solution to set negative padding values in Jetpack Compose? (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Padding must be non-negative)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to assign a negative value to the padding modifier but the app had crashed. Have a look at my code. Thanks if you can help or give me an alternative solution

In my example, I assign `Modifier.padding(horizontal = 16.dp)`to parent compose (LazyColum). But I want the first child (Image) to be `Modifier.padding(horizontal = -16.dp)` to fill the full width of the screen. Instead, I had to assign each `padding` value to each child.

Crash log: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Padding must be non-negative`

[image]

Code snippet

```
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp), state = lazyListState) {
    item {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(-16.dp) // Crashed here!
                .height(200.dp),
            painter = painterResource(id = puppy.artwork),
            contentDescription = "Puppy ArtWork",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
    }
    item {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                .padding(top = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = puppy.name, style = MaterialTheme.typography.h4)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            Price(puppy.pricePerHour)
        }
    }
    item {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp)
                text = puppy.about
            )
        }
    }
    item {
        PuppyInfo(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 16.dp),
            puppy = puppy
        )
    }
    .... // A lot of children here
    
}
```

Answer (score 67):

The padding modifier doesn't support negative values, but you can use the `offset` modifier instead:

```kotlin
val columnPadding = 16.dp
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.padding(columnPadding), state = lazyListState) {
    item {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .offset(x = -columnPadding)
                .height(200.dp),
            ...
        )
    }
    ...
```

That being said, I'd prefer using a `Column` with the image and a `LazyColumn` with the content (and applied padding) here instead.

```kotlin
Column {
    Image(...)
    LazyColumn(Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        ... all content here
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried your both solution but it not working for me! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'd need a little more info than that :)

Answer (score 10):

If you want to increase not only the positioning but also the width in both horizontal directions, you can use the `layout()` modifier.
I wrote a modifier extension function which can be used to ignore the parent padding:

```
fun Modifier.ignoreHorizontalParentPadding(horizontal: Dp): Modifier {
    return this.layout { measurable, constraints ->
        val overridenWidth = constraints.maxWidth + 2 * horizontal.roundToPx()
        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints.copy(maxWidth = overridenWidth))
        layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
            placeable.place(0, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use requiredWidth() to give the absolute width of Box(). You can also add padding to it if needed.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .requiredWidth(LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp)
        .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
){
    //...
}
```

[image]